# how to achive multiple or condition in libreoffice calc

Tags: libreoffice-calc

This is my Or condition **=OR(H4<0.5,I4<0.5,J4<0.5,K4<0.5)** but it  won't work in libreoffice . but it work on google sheet you can see the images how to achieve this [image: Libre office work] [image: google sheet]

Comment: I cannot confirm - your formula is working correctly. Please check the status of [AutoCalculate](https://help.libreoffice.org/7.1/en-US/text/scalc/01/06070000.html) option

Comment: Would be nice to get copyable data to reproduce your situation. Currently, I can't confirm your problem, because I can see only the OR-conditions for the cells (H4<0.5,I4<0.5,J4<0.5,K4<0.5) - and your shown result is correct.